# Connect React Material UI: Mini Variant + Responsive drawer

Tags: reactjs, drawer

I am new to React and Material UI and I've been trying really hard to connect Mini Variant Drawer that I have now with Responsive drawer, so when you use it on phone it changes to Responsive drawer. If anyone could help me it would mean a lot to me, I tried but I always failed.
It would also help me get the knowledge for further connections with drawers.

Here is my code that I use for Mini Variant Drawer:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import MenuOpenIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MenuOpen';

import { MainListItems } from './listItems';
import AccountMenu from '../../components/AccountMenu'
import ChangePasswordDialog from './ChangePasswordDialog';



const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 60, 
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  menuButtonHidden: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  mainTitle: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginLeft: 12
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: 'relative',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: 'hidden',
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 7,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 9,
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    display: 'flex',
    overflow: 'auto',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  fixedHeight: {
    height: 240,
  },
}));

export default function SideMenuLayout({
  drawerOpen,
  setDrawerOpen,
  children,
  title
}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setDrawerOpen(true);
  };
  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setDrawerOpen(false);
  };
  
  const [changePasswordDialogOpen, setChangePasswordDialogOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="absolute" className={clsx(classes.appBar, drawerOpen && classes.appBarShift)}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, drawerOpen && classes.menuButtonHidden)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.title}>
            
            {drawerOpen ? title : `MyTitle - ${title}`}
          </Typography>
        

          <AccountMenu onChangePassword={() => setChangePasswordDialogOpen(true)} />          
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: clsx(classes.drawerPaper, !drawerOpen && classes.drawerPaperClose),
        }}
        open={drawerOpen}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.mainTitle}>
            MyTitle
          </Typography>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            <MenuOpenIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List><MainListItems /></List>
        
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
        {children}
      </main>
      
      <ChangePasswordDialog
        isOpen={changePasswordDialogOpen}
        setOpen={setChangePasswordDialogOpen}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

I too have stumbled upon some issue trying to mix together the two drawer variants, but after a couple of hours I've found a configuration that seems to work properly.

**NOTE**: I'm absolutely no expert in JS/CSS/HTML, I'm way more a backend guy, so this solution can certainly be optimized and modified to fit your needs.

In my case the drawer is used to select the "page" to display. So I'll start from there.

The "page" component simply contains a `Router`. Its contents are put inside a `Box` with `display: flex`:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Box sx={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <HomePageInner />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/">
                         <p>Example</p>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Box>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

The `HomePageInner` is the component that renders the "menu" and appbar.
It keeps tracks of the open/closed status:

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

const HomePageInner = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
    const toggleDrawer = () => setOpen(!open);
    const drawer = <DrawerContents onClick={toggleDrawer} />;
    return (
        <>
            <MainAppBar open={open} onClick={toggleDrawer}/>
            <Box
                component="nav"
                aria-label="menu items"
            >
                <MobileDrawer open={open} onClose={toggleDrawer} drawer={drawer}/>
                <DesktopDrawer open={open} drawer={drawer}/>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
}
```

Here you can see that for clarity I have defined two distinct components for "mobile" and for "desktop". The *contents* of the drawer are shared and are defined in a separate `DrawerContents` component that is passed as a child.

There is an outer `Box` that wraps both `Drawer`s. In the examples on this `Box` there is an `sx` property that specifies `width: {sm: drawerWidth}, flexShrink: {sm :0}`, **the `flexShrink` should be removed**, but trying to add/remove the `width` setting does not seem to do anything, but *if something is broken for you try to set that property.*

The `DrawerContents` is pretty simple. It places the "chevron" icon button on the top that can be used to toggle the state and shows the links:

```
const DrawerContents: FunctionComponent<{ onClick: () => void }> = (props) => {
    return <>
        <Toolbar
            sx={{
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
                px: [1],
            }}
        >
            <IconButton onClick={props.onClick}>
                <ChevronLeftIcon/>
            </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
        <Divider/>
        <List>
            <ListItemLink primary="First" to="/first" icon={<DashboardIcon/>}/>
        </List>
        <List>
            <ListItemLink primary="Second" to="/second" icon={<TodayIcon/>}/>
        </List>
        <Divider/>
        <List>
            <ListItemLink primary="Third" to="/third" icon={<SettingsIcon/>}/>
        </List>
    </>;
}
```

Now for the interesting part! The `Drawer`s and the `AppBar`. So, the `MobileDrawer` is pretty much exactly the same as the `temporary` drawer in the "Responsive Drawer" example:

```
const MobileDrawer: FunctionComponent<{ container?: (() => any), open: boolean, onClose: () => void }> = (props) => {
    return <Drawer
        variant="temporary"
        container={props.container}
        open={props.open}
        onClose={props.onClose}
        ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true,
        }}
        sx={{
            display: {xs: "block", sm: "none"},
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {boxSizing: "border-box", width: drawerWidth},
        }}
    >
        {props.children}
    </Drawer>;
}
```

For the `DesktopDrawer` is mostly the same of the `permanent` drawer in th Responsive Drawer example however you have to modify the styling in the `sx` property so that it changes width when the status changes:

```
const DesktopDrawer: FunctionComponent<{ open: boolean }> = (props) => {
    return <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        sx={{
            display: {xs: "none", sm: "block"},
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
                position: "relative",
                whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                width: drawerWidth,
                transition: theme => theme.transitions.create('width', {
                    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
                }),
                boxSizing: "border-box",
                ...(!props.open && {
                    overflowX: "hidden",
                    transition: theme => theme.transitions.create('width', {
                        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
                    }),
                    width: theme => ({xs: theme.spacing(7), sm: theme.spacing(9)}),
                })
            },
        }}
        open={props.open}
    >
        {props.children}
    </Drawer>;
}
```

Note that here I made ample use of the function form of the `sx` properties that gives you access to the `theme`. I derived the correct values by "mergin" the values I saw in the Mini-Variant example and the Responsive example.

And now the `MainAppBar`. This too is quite similar to the Responsive Drawer example, however again we have to modify the `sx` property:

```
const MainAppBar: FunctionComponent<{ open: boolean, onClick: () => void }> = (props) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const headers: { [key: string]: string } = {
        '/first': "First",
        '/second': "Second",
        '/third': "Third",
    };

    return <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        sx={{
            zIndex: theme => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
            transition: theme => theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
                easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
            }),
            ...(props.open && {
                ml: {sm: `${drawerWidth}px`},
                width: {sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`},
                transition: theme => theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
                    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
                }),
            })
        }}
    >
        <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                edge="start"
                onClick={props.onClick}
                sx={{mr: 2}}
            >
                <MenuIcon/>
            </IconButton>
            <Typography
                component="h1"
                variant="h6"
                color="inherit"
                noWrap
                sx={{flexGrow: 1}}
            >
                {headers[location.pathname] || "Error"}
            </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>;
}
```

Note that here you want to:

- remove the `display: { sm: 'none' }` in the `sx` of the `IconButton` to toggle the state
- The `width` and `ml` settings must be included only in the `open` state

---

With all this configuration I get a drawer that for larger screen can be opened/closed like the mini variant:
[image: sample app with menu closed on the left, it only shows the icons]
[image: sample app with menu open on the left, it shows icons and text. Content of the app is "moved" to the right]

But is also responsive:
[image: picture of a sample app with the menu closed, the contents take all the width]
[image: picture of a sample app with the menu opened, the menu is shown above the content "like a modal dialog"]

PS: I didn't have the time to write a short answer, so I wrote a long one by copy&pasting my code and cutting away some stuff. If I find some time I might modify the sample code to be shorter and/or be self-contained.

Comment: Is there a stackblitz sample available somewhere? I'm struggling to getting the elements together in my project.